# How can I "discover" the COM object behind the ref counted handle in WinDbg?

Tags: .net, windbg

I'm investigating a memory leak via a WinDbg DMP file.  I've found that there are many instances of `AmazeType` on the heap, and although it is an excellent type, there are *way* too many in existence.  I'd like to know who is hoarding them.

`!gcroot`-ing `AmazeType` leads me to a "ref counted handle".  This makes sense, as the list of awesome type is stored in a property of a COM object instance, via a COM Callable Wrapper.

```
0:047> !gcroot 00000001c093e448
HandleTable:
    00000000015041a0 (ref counted handle)
    -> 00000001c0932fd8 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[AmazeType, AmazeAssembly]]
    -> 00000001c0927ef8 BaseAmazeType[]
    -> 00000001c093e448 AmazeType
```

What can one do with the ref counted handle `00000000015041a0` to obtain information about the RCW and the COM object it relates to?  If nothing, how could one alternately attack the problem?

Comment: Have you tried using [Debug Diagnostics](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924) with your dump? With many problems including memory leaks this tool can more easily show/highlight the underlying problem.

Comment: @Igor yes, I have tried it with the dump.  It suggests that the finalizer is blocked, which I'm looking at.  Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Can you `!do poi(15041a0)` and see if it gives something useful? I think this was the approach for strong and pinned handles.

Comment: A COM object must always have an RCW as well. You could check for those RCWs on the heap (`System.__ComObject` iirc) and use SOS `!dumprcw` or SOSEX `!rcw`.

Comment: @ThomasWeller it's a RefCount handle and `!do poi(15041a0)` dumps the list of `AmazeType`, so doesn't seem to get me closer to the COM type it's referenced by.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't done this in a 64-bit dump, only a 32-bit dump, but hopefully this will be of some help to you.

(I realise this is likely to be too late for you, but hopefully it will help somebody else.)

In my experience, going *from* the COM object to the .NET object runs like this. Therefore, going from the .NET object to the COM object is a case of reversing the process. I'm using examples from a real dump, but censored and renamed.

**From COM to .NET object.**

You have your COM object which has a field in it, which may look like this:

```
+0x30 m_iTestObject    : ATL:CComPtr<ITestObject> { 0e645150 }
```

Is that pointing, indirectly, to a clr!Unknown_QueryInterface? If not, it's not a CCW:

```
0:000> dds poi(0e645150) L1
0631c090  07466260 clr!Unknown_QueryInterface
```

OK, it is a CCW. We go back to the original address, 0e645150 and at this point we have to check a few offsets, because they seem to vary between .NET runtimes. The three offsets I've found so far are -0x0c, -0x10, and -0x14. Obviously the offsets may be different under 64-bit, but you can see that it should be pretty easy to try different offsets and then run !mdt against the results:

```
0:000> dds poi(0e645150-0x0c) L1
2506a4c0  00000000
0:000> dds poi(0e645150-0x10) L1
01785bd8  08acc744
0:000> dds poi(0e645150-0x14) L1
00000000  ????????
```

We can now run !mdt (sosex) or !do on each of the results. As it happens, only one of these actually gave us a valid address, which is 08acc744:

```
0:000> !mdt 08acc744
08acc744 (TestAssembly.TestObject)
    requests:08accba8 (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[TestAssembly.TestRequest, TestAssembly]])
    notifySink:08aee138 (TestAssembly.SinkWrapper)
```

**Tracing back to the COM object which is pointing to this .NET object:**

We start with the same .NET object at 08acc744 and check its references. (You already used !gcroot to find the RefCounted Handle):

```
0:000> !refs 08acc744
Objects referenced by 08ACC744 
  NONE

Objects that reference 08ACC744 (TestAssembly.TestObject):
  RefCounted Handle at 01785BD8, AppDomain=0456F158
```

OK, so we have the handle. What's pointing to it?

```
0:000> s -d 0x00000000 L?0xffffffff 01785bd8 
0e645140  01785bd8 2506a4c0 0630ec60 00000000  .[x....%`.0.....
```

So this handle is pointed to from 0e645140. We know that, rather than pointing directly to this address, the next level points to an offset from here. Can we find anything pointing to any of those offset addresses?

```
0:000> s -d 0x00000000 L?0xffffffff 0e645140+0x0c
0:000> s -d 0x00000000 L?0xffffffff 0e645140+0x10 
27f90d68  0e645150 25d100e8 27fab0f8 00000000  PQd....%...'....
0:000> s -d 0x00000000 L?0xffffffff 0e645140+0x14
```

We have found a pointer at 27f90d68, which we expect to be a field inside a COM object. Let's dump the memory around that address:

```
0:000> dds 27f90d68-0x40
27f90d28  0537f8b8
27f90d2c  00000000
27f90d30  559965bd
27f90d34  88000000
27f90d38  15ffe604 TestCore2!ATL::CComObject<CTestContainer>::`vftable'
27f90d3c  15ffe5e4 TestCore2!ATL::CComObject<CTestContainer>::`vftable'
27f90d40  00000002
27f90d44  0000000e
27f90d48  ffffffff
27f90d4c  0000000f
27f90d50  00000010
27f90d54  1dc721d8
27f90d58  00000000
27f90d5c  27d6ef80
27f90d60  262b1ec0
27f90d64  00000001
27f90d68  0e645150
27f90d6c  25d100e8
27f90d70  27fab0f8
27f90d74  00000000
27f90d78  559965b4
```

We can see an object with a vftable starting slightly before our address, so hopefully our address is a field inside that object. (Beware that objects may well have gaps between vftable entries, where things like ATL sink pointers can reside, but as it happens this is the start of the object).

```
0:000> dt 27f90d38  TestCore2!ATL::CComObject<CTestContainer>
   +0x000 __VFN_table : 0x15ffe604 
   =16010f38 _tih             : ATL::CComTypeInfoHolder
   +0x004 __VFN_table : 0x15ffe5e4 
   =16010f58 _tih             : ATL::CComTypeInfoHolder
   +0x008 m_dwRef          : 0n2
   +0x008 m_pOuterUnknown  : 0x00000002 IUnknown
   +0x00c m_nStateOrdinal  : 0n14
   +0x010 m_nKeyOrdinal    : 0n-1
   +0x014 m_nErrorCodeOrdinal : 0n15
   +0x018 m_nErrorTextOrdinal : 0n16
...
   +0x30 m_iTestObject    : ATL:CComPtr<ITestObject> { 0e645150 }
```

So that takes us all the way back from the .NET object into the COM object which is pointing to it.

I hope that's useful.

Comment: Thanks Peter.  As you guessed, I'm long passed needing this, but I appreciate your answer, so I've accepted it.  I have no idea if it actually works, but it looks plausible and I can't think of any reason why you'd make up a WinDBG answer! :-)  Good luck on your SO journey.